# Retrieving selected values from ListBox with multiselect

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, anonymous-types, multi-select

I have one WPF ListBox loaded using LINQ:

```
lbxCalculosSec.ItemsSource = from p in database.CALCULOS
                             orderby p.NOMBRECALCULO
                             select new { ID = p.IDCALCULO, NOMBRE = p.NOMBRECALCULO + " - " + p.DESCRIPCIONCALCULO };

lbxCalculosSec.DisplayMemberPath = "NOMBRE";
lbxCalculosSec.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
```

The listbox has multiselect = true. The problem is when I try to retrieve all the SelectedValue's  (ID's) from SelectedItems List.

When I inspect one SelectedItem at runtime, the object type is "<>f__AnonymousType0`2"

I tried using this:

```
ItemPropertyInfo ID  = null;

lbxCalculosSec.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(ID as ItemPropertyInfo, null)
```

But it didn't work.

I need a solution to access ListBox Selected Values (ID fields).

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetValue` expects the instance on which the property is defined, in this case it's the `SelectedItem`:

```
var item = lbxCalculosSec.SelectedItem;
ItemPropertyInfo ID  = (ItemPropertyInfo)item.GetType()
                                             .GetProperty("ID")
                                             .GetValue(item, null);
```

**Edit**
If `ID` is of some other type, like int, the code should be:

```
var item = lbxCalculosSec.SelectedItem;
int ID  = (int)item.GetType()
                   .GetProperty("ID")
                   .GetValue(item, null);
```

Comment: This solution works with a little change. ID has to be int type, and not ItemPropertyInfo.

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue` is expecting source for value so you should use SelectedItem there, not some random value and definitely not null.